Terminate GitHub Action job immediately based on job log content
I have a github action, which executes cypress tests. These tests are "crashing" sometimes with an unexpected error.
Edit: add shortened version of actions file.
jobs:
  build-docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: # [...]
  tests:
    timeout-minutes: 30
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build-docker
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        test_runs: [
          "test-group-1",
        ]
    steps:
      - name: Docker login
        # [...]
      - name: Pull docker image to local runner
        # [...]
      - name: Run tests
        uses: addnab/docker-run-action@v3
        with:
          image: "${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}/${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION }}"
          options: --env TEST_RUN=${{ matrix.test_runs }}
          shell: bash
          run: "/app/entrypoint.sh" # <- within this script, ECONNRESET is thrown sometimes 
        

Your configFile threw an error from: cypress.config.js

We stopped running your tests because your config file crashed.

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:218:20)

Currently, there is no real solution for fixing this error, but I want to fail the job immediately when this message occurs in the job log. The problem is, that the runner is actively waiting here and runs in a 30min timeout before failing the job.
Is it possible to fail the job regarding this output in the job log, saving time and github minutes?

It would help if you add your action file.
